# script used to extract data from pipe-delimited CSV file fails

Tags: regex, windows, powershell

I created a shell script that takes a CSV file and uses a regex to match data and outputs that data to another CSV file. However, when I run the script I get an error saying:

[image]

file_processor.ps1

```
$input_path = ‘c:\shell_scripting\input.csv’
$output_file = ‘c:\shell_scripting\output.csv’
$regex = ‘^(?:[^|]*\|){2}([^|]*)’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

input.csv:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6||8|9|10
```

I have checked the regex and it works:
http://www.regexr.com/3bj9p

Comment: The error line in the message doesn't match the posted script.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @mjolinor means that the regular expression in the error is not the same as the one in your script.

Comment: Why are you parsing the file manually? `Convertfrom-CSV`, `Import-CSV` & `Export-CSV` all accept the `Delimiter` parameter which will let you specify the `|` character instead of the default comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests an encoding issue. Most likely you have typographic quotes in your script (please avoid those) and saved it UTF-8 encoded without BOM. Because of that the opening typographic quote (which consist of 3 bytes in UTF-8) is read as 3 characters (`â€~`). Without the quotes PowerShell doesn't recognize the string as a string and throws a syntax error.

Comment: that's exactly what it was :)